How to export multiple profiles with env variables for different command in Makefile?
I'd like to create a Makefile which allows me to run a script on different environments what depends on secret ENV_VAR and exposed ENV environment variables:
export ENV_VAR=<secret_env_var>

setup: 
    python my_script.py

dev_setup: export ENV:=dev
dev_setup: setup

test_setup: export ENV:=test
test_setup: setup

I can include secrets in the separate file adding include config_dev.env file containing ENV_VAR for dev env. But for test env I should change the line to include config_test.env with another secret ENV_VAR.
I don't see the possibility to define instruction include into the command step how it is done with export ENV environment variables.
Or how it should be done in a proper way?
I tried this, commenting/uncommenting the first lines of code
include config_dev.env
#include config_test.env

export ENV_VAR=<secret_env_var>

setup: 
    python my_script.py

dev_setup: export ENV:=dev
dev_setup: setup

test_setup: export ENV:=test
test_setup: setup


You haven't clearly defined the parameters of the question, but isn't it enough to add something like CONFIG_TYPE = dev followed by include config_$(CONFIG_TYPE).env, then if you want to run the test version you invoke make CONFIG_TYPE=test ?

I intend to run make dev_setup and make test_setup commands to run python script with different configurations on different environments

That previously unstated requirement is what I meant by "you haven't clearly defined the parameters of the question".  Next question is, do you really need to include the .env file in your makefile at all?  Why not just set it in the recipe for the setup target, something like setup: ; . config_$(ENV).env && ENV_VAR=<secret_env_var> python my_script.py ?

just to have a short command typing in terminal

My suggestion in my last comment doesn't require extra typing in the terminal.

Have you tried a Taskfile? It's much easier to handle a lot of things.
https://taskfile.dev/usage/#environment-variables

I don't quite understand how secrecy attaches to the value ENV_VAR
though its being set from an include-ed file, but the make-time choice
to set ENV and ENV_VAR to their dev values or their test values
can be made depending on whether the make target is dev_setup or
test_setup. Obviously they are mutually exclusive targets and I suppose
dev_setup can be the default.
$ cat Makefile 
target := $(MAKECMDGOALS)
ifeq (,$(target))
target := dev_setup
endif

ifeq (dev_setup,$(target))
include config_dev.env
export ENV := dev
else
ifeq (test_setup,$(target))
include config_test.env
export ENV := test
else
$(error Choose one target: dev_setup (default) or test_setup)
endif
endif

export ENV_VAR:=$(secret_env_var)

.PHONY: setup dev_setup test_setup

$(target): setup
    @echo $(target) done

setup:
    @python3 -c "import os;print('ENV =', os.getenv('ENV'));print('ENV_VAR =', os.getenv('ENV_VAR'))"
    @echo Setup done.
    

$ cat config_dev.env 
secret_env_var=dev_setup_secret


$ cat config_test.env 
secret_env_var=test_setup_secret


$ make
ENV = dev
ENV_VAR = dev_setup_secret
Setup done.
dev_setup done


$ make dev_setup
ENV = dev
ENV_VAR = dev_setup_secret
Setup done.
dev_setup done


$ make test_setup
ENV = test
ENV_VAR = test_setup_secret
Setup done.
test_setup done


$ make test_setup dev_setup
Makefile:14: *** Choose one target: dev_setup (default) or test_setup. Stop.

GNU Make manual references:-
7.2 Syntax of Conditionals
9.2 Arguments to Specify the Goals
